# Lambda function access to EC2 instance in same security group

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to access my EC2 instance configured with elasticsearch from a configured lambda function.
I've added the lambda function to the same VPC and security group as the EC2 instance. I am not sure; what's causing the issue ?
I've EC2FullAccess permissions from lambda function

Answer (score 0):

The correct security configuration should be:

- A security group on the Lambda function (`Lambda-SG`). It does not require any Inbound rules. Leave the Outbound rules as standard 'allow all'.
- A security group on the EC2 instance (`Elasticsearch-SG`) that allows Inbound connections on the desired port (9200?) from the `Lambda-SG`.

That is, `Elasticsearch-SG` specifically allows inbound connections from `Lambda-SG`.

Please note that **security group rules apply to each instance individually**. Putting two resources 'in' the same security group does not permit access between those resources unless there is a rule that allows inbound access from itself. Thus, it is better to put different security groups on each layer of resources.

There is no need to assign `EC2FullAccess` permissions to the Lambda function. That is only used to call AWS to do things like launching or terminating EC2 instances.